# Getting last instance of a pattern using GREP

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file, file.log, in the following format:

```
23/05 04:15:10,072  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Calculation Com 
23/05 08:22:27,862  [INFO ] test    End Batch Calculation Com 
27/07 01:15:10,072  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Calculation Com 
27/07 06:22:27,862  [INFO ] test    End Batch Calculation Com 
27/07 06:22:36,192  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Fact 
27/07 06:22:36,896  [INFO ] test    End Batch Fact 
27/07 06:22:43,607  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Edition
27/07 06:22:44,888  [INFO ] test    End Batch Edition
23/05 01:15:10,072  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Calculation Com 
23/05 06:22:27,862  [INFO ] test    End Batch Calculation Com 
23/05 06:22:36,192  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Fact 
23/05 06:22:36,896  [INFO ] test    End Batch Fact 
23/05 06:22:43,607  [INFO ] test    Start Batch Edition
23/05 06:22:44,888  [INFO ] test    End Batch Edition
```

I am writing a ksh script to get the time which contains the string End Batch Calculation Com of the 23/05.  23/05 is the actual date.
Below is my code:

```
TimeCom=$(grep 'End Batch Calculation Com' file.log |grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')")
TimeEnd=`expr substr "$TimeCom" 7 8`
echo "$TimeEnd"
```

However, this is returning the time of the 1st instance of 23/05 .... End Batch Calculation Com :  08:22:27

What I want is to get the time of the last instance of 23/05 .... End Batch Calculation Com :  06:22:27

Any idea how to do this?

I tried using tac but this does not work :

```
TimeCom=$(tac file.log | grep 'End Batch Calculation Com' file.log |grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')")
```

Comment: Add `| tail -1` just before closing parenthesis on first line.

Comment: What does your `tac` solution gives you ? What do you mean with `The tail -1 will not work as the file is a log which is continuous`, do you want to keep grepping for the next 100 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
grep 'End Batch Calculation Com' Input_file |grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')" | tail -1
```

Explanation is I have simply added tail -1 to get the final occurrence.

**EDIT:**
Here is a solution with awk also.

```
awk -v DATE=$(date +'%d/%m') '/End Batch Calculation Com/ && $0 ~ DATE{VAL=$0} END{print VAL}'   Input_file
```

So searching here for string "ENd Batch Calculation Com/ then taking first field to a variable named VAL then in END section of awk printing it so it will always print the last occurrence of the match value. You could put this into a variable too by using VAL=$(....)

Comment: The tail -1 will not work as the file is a log which is continuous.  I tried adding tac before the grep, it does not work.  I have edited my question

Comment: I added 1 awk command, solution too now, kindly give it a try too now.

Answer (score 1):

With single ***grep*** piped with `tail -n1` (to get the last matched line):

```
d=$(date +%d/%m)
grep "^$d .* End Batch Calculation Com" file | tail -n1
```

The output:

```
23/05 06:22:27,862  [INFO ] test    End Batch Calculation Com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeCom=$(grep "^$(date +'%d/%m').*End Batch Calculation Com" file.log | sort -nr | head -n1 )
TimeEnd=`expr substr "$TimeCom" 7 8`
echo "$TimeEnd"
```

So, I added a numeric reverse sort, so the latest time is on the first line.

Edit: after your edit, the sort is unnecessary and you can just use `tail -n 1` like in the other answers, si

```
TimeCom=$(grep "^$(date +'%d/%m').*End Batch Calculation Com" file.log | tail -n 1 )
TimeEnd=`expr substr "$TimeCom" 7 8`
echo "$TimeEnd"
```

Comment: This does not work.  It still give me the first instance.

Comment: If I use the log file in your question, I get `06:22:27` now. Did you try after the edit ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to pipe the output to `tail -n 1`. However, if you have a big file it should be more efficient to reverse the lines using `tac` and `grep -m 1` to get the first match (that is, the last match in the original file).

If your input had ISO timestamps at the start of the line you could simply pipe it through `sort` to order them. As it is, you'll first have to **swap the month and date** (and never use anything other than ISO dates in files):

```
sed -e 's#\([0-9]*\)/\([0-9]*\)#\2/\1#'
```